# GlassFish Server, deploy, Permission denied: connect, false

Tags: java, netbeans, server, glassfish

Please help me.
My glassfish server is showing above error message continuously, I have already tried other solutions. Please provide the real one.

```
[[![!\[][1]][1]This is what I get the output. I got nothing from logs. Please help me out][1]][1]
```

Comment: What error. Post your error here

Comment: To post _real_ answer you should [edit] your question and post some error logs here. And also which OS you're using? Are you using any antivirus programs (like K7)? :)

Comment: Update your post to list the "other solutions" you have tried. This shows that you have made some effort, and saves time being wasted on people proposing approaches that you have already tried. As it stands your post shows no research effort at all, and you should address that.